# convert elastic result returned by elastic sql to general elastic result

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic 6.7 and using sql to fetch data from elastic. Now weird format of data is returned from elastic when I am using Sql, it looks like:

```
 {
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "DeviceType",
      "type": "text"
    },
    {
      "name": "epoch timestamp in milisecods",
      "type": "datetime"
    },
    {
      "name": "number of events",
      "type": "long"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
      "2019-09-24T08:13:00.000Z",
      1
    ]
  ],
  "cursor": "m8DyAgFjARBzYS1zaWduYWwtZXZlbnRzygEBAQljb21wb3NpdGUHZ3JvdXBieQAA/wIBBjEwNzQwOQEJY3JlYXRlZE9uAAEFAf8AAAAAAAAAAOpgAAEDVVRDAAYxMDczODIBEmN1c3RvbWVySWQua2V5d29yZAAAAf8AAOgHAQoCBjEwNzQwOQIAAAFtYlSu4AYxMDczODIAJDExMTExMTExLTExMTEtMTExMS0xMTExLTExMTExMTExMTExMQACAQAAAAABAP////8PAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAVoDAAICAAAAAAAB9f///w8DAWsGMTA3MzgyAAFaAAFrBjEwNzQwOQABWgEBawYxMDczODIBAVoAAQc="
}
```

now when I fire the same thing in ES query I get a result set as:

```
data : [{
        "deviceType": "laptops",
        "data" : [
            [
                "epoch timestamp in milisecods",
                "number of events"
            ],[
                "epoch timestamp in milisecods",
                "number of events"
            ],[
                "epoch timestamp in milisecods",
                "number of events"
            ],[
                "epoch timestamp in milisecods",
                "number of events"
            ]
            ]
        }
    ]
```

so is there any way or API to convert sql returned data into ES query returned data?

sql query:

> {"query": "select HISTOGRAM(createdOn, INTERVAL 30 MINUTES) as created,deviceType from \"indexName\" where customerId = 'xxxx' group by created,deviceType"}

P.S. - above-shown thing in quotes are just to show data format. And they are in JSON format. It's just the way elastic is throwing result.

Comment: Add your SQl query

Comment: added sql query. @jaspreetchahal

Comment: SQL response formats will give you data in row and column format. You won't get it as in elastic search -- buckets. You can use format=txt for tabular format.You can look for different formats https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-rest-format.html

Comment: @jaspreetchahal not working, i am getting similar result

Comment: I am checking in kibana POST /_sql?format=txt
{
  "query": """select HISTOGRAM(createdOn, INTERVAL 30 MINUTES) as created,deviceType.keyword from "index-sql" where customerId.keyword = '1' group by created,deviceType.keyword"""
}. This is the response I get         created         |deviceType.keyword
------------------------+------------------
2019-03-20T00:00:00.000Z|B